# can i use boot2docker in production ? CoreOS Vs boot2docker

Tags: docker, boot2docker, coreos, dockerhub

If not why boot2docker cannot be used in production ?
what is the thing, coreOS brings that boot2docker doesn't have  ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[boot2docker](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/README.md#virtualbox-guest-additions) is the name of the Linux (tinyCore) VM used in non-Linux host (by, for instance, [`docker machine`](https://docs.docker.com/machine/migrate-to-machine/)).

If you go into production with Docker, it is best to do so on Linux host (where you don't need boot2docker anyway).

After that, it depends on your production environment: if it is a complex one (where clustering and service replication is a concern), *then* CoreOS proposes a platform (which does support docker): see "[7 reasons why you should be using CoreOS with Docker](https://www.airpair.com/coreos/posts/coreos-with-docker)"

[image: https://image.slidesharecdn.com/deis-141102221759-conversion-gate01/95/ceph-docker-heroku-slugs-coreos-and-deis-overview-15-638.jpg?cb=1414966883]

> CoreOS is a barebones Linux distribution designed to make large multiple-machine deployments, using different softwares and dependencies, easier to scale and easier to manage. It is built for high availability and security.
>
> It does not come with a package manager and thus requires containers such as those provided by Docker.
> It uses "fleet" for cluster management and "etcd" for service discovery and keeping configuration up to date across the cluster.

Comment: Thanks.If i plan to use docker + coreOS in AWS , AWS doesn't  handle cluster management by itself ?

Comment: @nkkrishnak cluster management, that would be ECS: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/cluster-management-with-amazon-ecs/

Comment: you can check options provided here in this link https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/aws/ kops or kube-aws